# Event sourcing: command bus

Tags: typescript, event-sourcing

Hello I'm doing a command bus to use something like:

commandbus.execute(new Command(commandDTO))

But I didn't want to use decorators to do this, so I thought of the following:

**Commands:**

```
export interface ICommandHandler<
  TCommand extends ICommand = any,
  TResult = any
> {
  execute(command: TCommand): Promise<TResult>;
}
export interface ICommandPublisher<CommandBase extends ICommand = ICommand> {
  publish<T extends CommandBase = CommandBase>(command: T): any;
}
    export interface ICommand {}
```

**CommandBus:**

```
export interface ICommandBus<CommandBase extends ICommand = ICommand> {
  execute<T extends CommandBase>(command: T): Promise<any>;
    register(command:ICommand, handlers: readonly ICommandHandler[]): void;
}

export class CommandBus {
execute<T extends CommandBase>(command: T): Promise<any> {
    const commandName = this.getCommandName(command as any);
    const handler = this.handlers.get(commandName);
    if (!handler) throw new CommandHandlerNotFoundException(commandName);
    this.subject$.next(command);
    return handler.execute(command);
  }

  bind<T extends CommandBase>(handler: ICommandHandler<T>, name: string) {
    this.handlers.set(name, handler);
  }

  register(command: ICommand, handlers: ICommandHandler<any, any>[]) {
    handlers.forEach((handler) =>
      this.registerHandler(this.getCommandName(command), handler)
    );
  }

  protected registerHandler(
    commandName: string,
    handler: ICommandHandler<CommandBase, any>
  ) {
    this.bind(handler, commandName);
  }

  private getCommandName(command: ICommand): string {
    const { constructor } = Object.getPrototypeOf(command);
    return constructor.name as string;
  }
}
export class ObservableBus<T> extends Observable<T> {
  protected _subject$ = new Subject<T>();

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.source = this._subject$;
  }

  public get subject$() {
    return this._subject$;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem like a pleasant thing, that is, I would have to register in the command bus in a grotesque way:

register ([{commandA, event A}, {commandb, eventb}])

I would like to know if anyone can help me in a way that I can popularize the commandbus by reading the folder and taking the defaults from the files,

Should I put a property in each event by linking to each command name?

or put an event name that you will call in each command file?

Comment: Have you considered using simple types instead of classes for commands and using an `eventName` property?

Comment: @Evert hmmm no,I changed my event with an event_name property, to save it to my db event-store
could you give me an example ?? I didn’t quite understand what the logic would look like ..

Comment: Your code is missing the types for `ICommand`, `CommandBase`, and `ICommandHandler` so it's hard to understand what's going on.  Can you update with a complete code?

Comment: A typescript class has to define it's own properties, so you need to include `handler` and `subject$` in the class.  They either need to have an initial value or be set in the constructor.

Comment: It looks like `this.handlers` is a `Map` and if that's the case then you can only have one handler per event.

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes this.handlers is a map with key is command name, i edit with full interfaces.